# Fastest control to block duplicates

Tags: vb.net

I am looking for a control example and array or dictionary or listview where I can add about 30,000 items and then try to add the exact same 30,000 items and block the adding process because they're duplicates.. what do you guys recommend for speed stability?

Comment: are you looking for a control with a `NoDuplicates` type property?  why not decline to add an item if it already exists?  A dictionary is not a control but provides the perfect means to check for and prevent duplicates (depending on the definition)

Comment: I am looking for anything that allows me to prevent duplicates and has speed, do you have any sample code?

Comment: no code required.  it is how a dictionary works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hashtable is the fastest by far. You can ask if the HT has the item already and if not, add it to the HT.  This MSDN link has all the info and examples you could want:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx

Comment: +1 for hashtable. I took over a legacy application that was using array lists for this same thing and I increased performance exponentially by implementing a hashtable instead.